# PaperJS updated centre not redrawing

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am using Paper.js to draw a circle on screen.
I update the centre position in update but the screen doesn't display draw the circle with the updated position.

```
class Ball{
    this.graphics = new Path.Circle({
        center: [200,200],
        radius: 20,
        fillColor: 'blue'
    });
  }
  update(){
    //test
    this.graphics.center = [100,100]
  }
}

var ball = new Ball();

//update
view.onFrame = function(event) { 
    ball.update();
}
```

The circle is always drawn on 200,200 no matter what values I update `this.graphics.centre` with.
I have also tried adding `view.draw();` in `view.onFrame()` after `ball.update()` but it didn't change anything.

I have made sure the rest of the code is working since if I instead create a new Path.Circle() in `ball.update()` it draws a new circle on the correct position.

Comment: There is no property called center on the Path.Circle, but there is a position property..  A slight inconsistent API there. :)   .. So try changing to position.

Comment: @Keith Changing to position worked, thanks! Maybe a noob question but does this mean that the constructor for Path.Circle(...) takes in an argument called center while the respective property in the object has the name position?

Comment: Yes, it looks like that.  I'm not a PaperJS user, but I assume the developer wanted to make it obvious that the position is the circle centre,. But position is common with other object, so calling it center here wouldn't have been ideal.